# Ubuntu 20.10 does not change audio output device when connected to bluetooth headphone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 20.10

I have Ubuntu 20.10 running on a Dell G5 5590. The machine is plugged to an external monitor (which has speakers) via minidisplay port. Using this setup the audio works as expected, I can change the audio output devices between the internal speakers and monitor speakers.

However, when I connect my bluetooth headphone, things start to get strange. Now, when I go to the sound settings and change the output device, the device is changed on the UI, but the sound only goes through the bluetooth headphone. Also, when the output device is not the bluetooth headphone (even though the audio is always going through the bluetooth headphone) I cannot change adjust the volume. The volume setting only works when the bluetooth heaphone is set as the output device.

Answer (score 0):

I use 20.10 and I have to set other profiles to "Off" and only BT headphone must be valid profile. In this case I can hear the audio in headphone. I have to set BT headphone "Off" and change other profile active to hear sound there.

Try this maybe works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I do that? I don't see an option for that on the Settings app.